# How Do I order a Django model by name?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have got a list of products from **different** retailers. I am trying to sort the list to try and **group all products that are the same** but have **different retailers** together. I am trying to sort the model by 'product', so that it is presented in order in the Django **admin** panel, and so that I can carry out commands on a product group at once. How should I go about doing this?

Model:

```
class RetailerProduct(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=300,null=True,blank=True) 
    price =  models.DecimalField(default=0.00,max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    difference = models.DecimalField(default=0.00,max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    retailer = models.ForeignKey(Retailer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='sources')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.retailer.name + " - " + self.product.name
```

I have tried using:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('product',)
```

But it does not work.

**Thanks everyone for contributing**

Comment: What error are you getting?  Have you tried making it a list type, (following the docs)?[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20to,ordering%20%3D%20%5B%27pub_date%27%5D]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you migrate after putting the meta in the models.py file? If you did, and it still doesn't work, you may have to create a admin view yourself.

In admin.py, try this:

```
class RetailerProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ["product"]
admin.site.register(RetailerProduct, RetailerProductAdmin)
```

Make sure you haven't already registered RetailerProduct. Also, make sure RetailerProduct is imported inside admin.py.

Answer (score 1):

inside `views.py`, you can try the following code, creating a dictionary with **ordered data** and pass the dictionary

```
from .models import your_model_name
def Meta(request):
    ordered_data = your_model_name.objects.order_by('product')
    context = {
        'data': ordered_data
    }
    return render(request, 'your.html', context)
```

to get reversed, add a '-' sign. try these

```
from .models import your_model_name
def Meta(request):
    ordered_data = your_model_name.objects.order_by('-product')
    context = {
        'data': ordered_data
    }
    return render(request, 'your.html', context)
```

to filter data:

```
from .models import your_model_name
def Meta(request):
    ordered_data = your_model_name.objects.order_by('-product').filter(your_filter==True)
    context = {
        'data': ordered_data
    }
    return render(request, 'your.html', context)
```